# What is the maximum limit of Google Pub/Sub Attributes value?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to use Google Pub/Sub in my project.
And I got error because it exceed the limit of attributes value.

Message: Client error: `POST https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project>/topics/<topic>:publish` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "One of the attributes in the request has a value that is too long. The l (truncated...)

I read the documentation on https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limits are specified in the [Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#resource_limits) sections of the documentation. An attribute key can be up to 256 bytes and an attribute value can be up to 1024 bytes.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is hard to spot.